# Преобразовать из curl в c#

Tags: c#, post, curl

Всем привет, пытаюсь преобразовать запрос вида: `curl --user "${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}" \ --data "grant_type=client_credentials" \ "https://api.ivideon.com/auth/oauth/token"` в С#, но вылезает 400 ошибка. Пробовал https://curl.olsh.me/, но тщетно. Спасибо за помощь!

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            await GetTokenAsync();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static async Task GetTokenAsync()
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.ivideon.com/auth/oauth/token"))
                {
                    var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}"));
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

                    request.Content = new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials");
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://curl.olsh.me/

Comment: добавьте пример вашего кода в воопрос

Comment: `"${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}"` замениете на `$"{CLIENT_ID}:{CLIENT_SECRET}"` и дальше компилятор подскажет, что делать. В самом низу еще можно написать `Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());` чтобы увидеть ответ от сервера.